# Replace extra spaces in word inside string

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

I have a huge list of strings that I am iterating through to create a dictionary. I don't know what will be in each string, because it is parsed out of a document filled with tables.

Sometimes a string will have extra spaces in it, or a space in the middle of a word where it didn't have that in the word document.

Is there a way to detect extra spaces between a word, and extra spaces between words.

**Example**

```
myString = 'I have  N o other way to get here'
myString = detectedDoubleSpace_After_Have_AndSpace_In_Middle_Of_No(myString.replace(stuff))
```

I am aware of regular expressions, the replace function, strip, lstrip, rstrip.
But, I don't know how I can specifically look for double spaces or spaces in the middle of a word.

## Edit

## Aparently this is a monumental task since detecting what is and isn't a word is an issue, which I hadn't considered.

Comment: There is no simple way to detect if `hel lo` is one word or 2. You should probably trawl some corpuses and build a dict/set of valid words, and then assume that any invalid word you encounter is actually a single word broken into two by a space.

Comment: It's really hard to know what a valid word is, unless you build a dictionary. For instance `to get her` is a valid set of 3 words, or an invalid set of one word (`together`) with two spaces... see the problem?

Comment: @Coldspeed That would be a huge amount of work since I'm parsing these lists from word documents. I was hoping there's a reasonably simple way to use regular expressions maybe. If there's not, I can live with that.

Comment: I'd suggest you fix your parsing so it doesn't put spaces between words that shouldn't be there

Comment: I had the same issue when doing text mining from ocred PDFs. Lots of extra spaces. What I did was extract all 2-grams, then if one of the two sides was not in my dictionary (list of inflected words) AND the concatenation was, then they're proposed for manual review. I didn't do it in English though. If you find a good list of inflected English words I think I can give you a satisfying solution tomorrow

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I appreciate the offer. At this point, now that I understand the issue better ,I don't think it's worth pursuing. It's more superficial for the purpose that I'm doing, so I don't think it's worth the extra effort and time.

Comment: @ProfessionalNameForDisplayHere It is a monumental task yes, but if you are willing to make some adjustments, there are ways to do it. You should consider taking a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the first of your issues is easily resolved. All you need to do is use regex to remove double spaces between words.

```
import re
your_text = ... # some text here

your_text_without_extra_spaces = re.sub('[\s]+', ' ', your_text, flags=re.M)
```

The second problem isn't as simple. However, one approach you *could* do is to look for some huge english language corpuses and build a set/dict out of them.

Or, you could use the NLTK package, and check for synsets of words in your string.

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

processed_text = ''
i = 0
words = your_text_without_extra_spaces.split()
while i < len(words):
    if not wordnet.synsets(words[i]) and i < len(words) - 1 and not wordnet.synsets(words[i + 1]):
        processed_text += words[i] + words[i + 1] + ' '
        i += 2
    else:
        processed_text += words[i] + ' '
        i += 1
```

You should refer to [this article](http://www.velvetcache.org/2010/03/01/looking-up-words-in-a-dictionary-using-python) if you have trouble installing wordnet or want to try other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Try `\s\s` to match double spaces between two words